# What does this sentence mean by saying in a region?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> IN A REGION where governments often disregard or contort their own
> laws, Singapore stands out for punctilious observance."

This line comes from an article in The Economist. **Perhaps you could search this sentence to find the whole text for better understanding.** (Well, actually I find it difficult to understand the whole sentence, but the question needs to be specific so I added some details. So please be aware that I need more explanations of the question than is asked.)

Is A REGION representing Singapore or an area including Singapore, and what is the relation between this region and Singapore? And why is it capitalized?

It seems Singapore carries the character of being punctilious observance, which conflicts with the region where the laws are often disregarded or contorted. So, is the reason for mentioning Singapore to protrude its observance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'In Asia (or maybe south east Asia), where governments often disregard or contort their own laws, Singapore stands out for punctilious observance.'

You did not give the origin of the article, which is *The Economist* of 5 March 2022. The region in which Singapore is located is Asia, or, more specifically, south east Asia. The section of the magazine is headed 'Asia'. To print the first few words of an article (the 'lead-in') in capital letters is a typographic style convention that publications sometimes follow. Others include showing the first letter of the first word in a large or decorative font.

[image]

Comment: OP could ask themself: how many government***s*** does Singapore have? Even though Singapore itself has five main regions, they are not "in a region".

Comment: @WeatherVane - er, what?

Comment: The post says "governments" in the plural. So 'region' can't be referring to Singapore itself, unless the plural refers to the local governments of its own regions, but then the sentence does not read very credibly.

Comment: @Weather Vane, here in Singapore,  each constituency is represented by a Member of Parliament.   We don't normally use the term 'local government'.

Comment: @SeowjoohengSingapore which makes it even less credible. In my country we have local areas represented by an MP, but we also have County Councils and Unitary Authorities, which is what 'local government' means. I am regretting the complications I caused, let's just stick with "governments" in the plural can't mean 'Singapore', which I though was fairly obvious.

Comment: @Weather Vane, no problem.  You are right on the "governments" matter. 
 That has also been explained in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

A region in this context usually refers to the specific place being discussed and areas that surround it or are associated with it. The author implies that other countries in this region are more loose with their enforcement of the law, so Singapore's characteristic of "punctilious observance" (enforcement of the law) is the exception to the general rule of lax laws in the region. The capitalization is a stylistic choice, used to signify the start of the text in some publications, known as a "lead-in".

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to understand if you flip the order of the sentence. The sentence you quoted is equivalent to this:

> Singapore stands out for punctilious observance in a region where governments often disregard or contort their own laws.

This means that Singapore stands out for its "punctilious observance" *specifically because* it is located in a region of the world (Southeast Asia) where governments disregard or contort their own laws.

As windwally said, the capitalization is stylistic and doesn't affect the meaning.